# What does scroll.scrolldisabler do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does this code do?

```
 var oldScrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
     $(window).on('scroll.scrolldisabler', function (evt) {
         $(window).scrollTop(oldScrollPos);
         evt.preventDefault();
 });
```

My codebase uses the code above, but I'm not quite sure why its useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: that code stops the user from scrolling the window, but the `".scrolldisabler"` part doesn't have any inherent meaning and isn't needed to make the code work. Whether preventing scrolling is "useful" depends on your requirements.

Long answer:

The first line stores the window's current scroll position in the variable `oldScrollPos`.

The call to `.on()` creates an event handler for the window "scroll" event. What the handler does is set the window's scroll position back to what was stored in the `oldScrollPos` variable, so this prevents the user from scrolling the window. (It also calls `.preventDefault()`, but I don't think that does anything in this case, because the scroll event is triggered after the scrolling has happened.)

The `".scrolldisabler"` part is an "event namespace", which is a jQuery feature: it is just an identifier that you can use to unbind this handler without affecting other scroll handlers, it is *not* part of the actual event name and has no particular technical meaning. This could be coded as `.on("scroll.hello"`, or `.on("scroll"` and it would still work the same way. The namespace only comes into play if you later call `.trigger()` or `.off()`.

For more information about jQuery event namespaces have a look at the [.on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).